# Google Script Question: Is there a way to create copies of files into multiple folders at once?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet from which I've written code to populate with the names of folders (column 1) and their IDs (column 2).

I would like to populate each of the folders listed in that spreadsheet with a copy of each of the documents contained a separate folder (a Shared Drive folder, if that matters). When I execute the code below, a copy of each document is created in the source folder (the Shared Drive folder) instead of in the destination folder (aka the folders whose IDs are captured in the spreadsheet). If it matters, each copy is labelled with a folderID from the spreadsheet. Can someone please tell me how I can get this code to create the copies inside the appropriate destination folders instead of in the source folder?

```
function CopiestoFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange() //Get all non-blank cells
                 .getValues() //Get array of values
                 .splice(1); //Remove header line
  //Define column numbers for data. Array starts at 0.
  var NAME = 0;
  var FOLDERID = 1;

  //For each folder ID listed in spreadsheet, create a copy of
  //each item in the Resume Resources folder.  

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i][NAME];
    var folderId = data[i][FOLDERID];

    var srcFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder ID");
    var dstFolder = folderId;
    var files = srcFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var f = file.makeCopy(dstFolder);
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
        dstFolder.addFile(file);
        f.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Hi, did your issue get solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Script Files.  Here's how I fixed.  Or I should say here's how Tanaike fixed it.  You will need to enable Drive API.

```
var res=file.makeCopy(copyName,subFldr);
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
        Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": subFldr.getId()}]}, res.getId(), null, {"supportsTeamDrives":true}); // Added
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, Cooper. Can you clarify what actually had to be fixed? In your example, it seems like you were moving files into a subfolder of your source file, is that correct?

Comment: It just changes the parent  subfolder of the file.  In other words, it moves it to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

The file.makeCopy() method has 3 overloads:

```
//Accepts no parameters
file.makeCopy();

//Accepts a name parameter as a string
file.makeCopy(name);

//Accepts a destination parameter as an instance of a Folder class
file.makeCopy(destination);

//Accepts 2 parameters, the first of which is name (String) and the second one is destination (Folder).
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
```

You are trying to pass folder id instead of the actual folder, which gets interpreted as a folder name (not destination). Also, the following code means that your 'dstFolder' parameter is a string but you try to call the 'addFile()' method on it:

```
var folderId = data[i][FOLDERID];
var dstFolder = folderId;
dstFolder.addFile(file);
```

Comment: Thank you, Anton. Any suggestions on how I can pass the actual folder rather than using the folder ID?

Comment: @GoogleScriptLearner calling “var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);” will return an instance of the Folder class that you can then pass to the file.makeCopy() method as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to copy a file to another folder via [makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination), you should pass a [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) as a parameter, not a folder id (a string). If you provide a string (your id) as a parameter, the script [will interpret](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname) this id as the `name` you want the copied file to have. So you should first get the Folder out of its id, via [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)). So you should change this line:

```
var dstFolder = folderId;
```

To this one:

```
var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
```

- You are making a copy of the file before checking if the file is a Google Apps Script project. I assume you just want GAS projects to be copied, so this should be included inside the `if` block. Also, inside the `if` block you are using [addFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)) which can also be used to copy a file to another folder (it adds the file to the desired folder). So you don't need to use both functions, they are doing basically the same (copying your file to the desired folder).
- You are using [removeFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removeFile(File)), which is not necessary if you want to keep the original files in the original folders.

So the `while` block could be something like:

```
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
        dstFolder.addFile(file);
      }
    }
```

Finally, your full code could be like:

```
function CopiestoFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange() //Get all non-blank cells
                 .getValues() //Get array of values
                 .splice(1); //Remove header line
  //Define column numbers for data. Array starts at 0.
  var NAME = 0;
  var FOLDERID = 1;

  //For each folder ID listed in spreadsheet, create a copy of
  //each item in the Resume Resources folder.  

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i][NAME];
    var folderId = data[i][FOLDERID];

    var srcFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder ID");
    var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);  
    var files = srcFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
        dstFolder.addFile(file);
      }
    }
  }     
}
```

I hope this is of any help.